# In git, Team -> Push to Upstream and Fetch from up stream is disabled for the work bench

Tags: git, github

In Git Staging viewer, I had ignored .gitignore  files, 
[image]

After that Im not able to commit or push to upstram or fetch from upstream are disabled.
[image]

Git status for the same.
[image]

updated status after git checkout --- appSettings.html
[image]

How can I fix This ?

Comment: What does `git status` show you from the Git Bash?

Comment: I am not used to git command line, updated the question with the status.

Comment: Your working directory is dirty and it needs to be cleaned before workbench will allow to proceed, q.v. my response below.

Comment: You should be able to pull and push now, at least from the Git Bash.  The untracked in there might be preventing the workbench for letting you do this, I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Had tried with git push -u <branch name>.. but not able to push

Comment: You may be behind the remote branch.  Try pulling first.

Comment: I am not used  to command line, if possible can you provide the command.

Comment: `git pull origin feature/CDC-225-cdc-ui-improvement` ... you should also figure out how to do this from the workbench.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108470/discussion-between-user630209-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1):

Git is refusing to let you pull or push because you have a modified file in your working directory:

```
CDC-WEB/src/main/webapp/src/master/appSettings.html
```

You have a few options here.  If you don't want these changes you can reset to the last commit via:

```
git checkout -- CDC-WEB/src/main/webapp/src/master/appSettings.html
```

If you do want to keep the changes, then you can consider either stashing or committing your work.  I am not very familiar with workbench, but the Bash command to stash is `git stash`.  If you choose to commit, you can treat the commit as being temporary.  In other words, you can always come back to the commit and amend it once you feel you have reached a good stopping point.

Comment: Don't want these changes, tried the command "git checkout -- CDC-WEB/src/main/webapp/src/master/appSettings.html", still im not able to push

Comment: What does `git status` now tell you?